# New ASP.net MVC Project - Log On not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Consider a new ASP.NET MVC project and haven't done any modifications to the code. I run the application and click the [Log On] link at the top right and try to register a new account. After about a minute it times out with the following:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I am running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: When you created the project with VS did you create the project on the server or on your development PC?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a local instance of SQL server express installed and running?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your web.config `<connectionStrings>` element. Within there, you'll see a connection string. Find the server or `data source` portion, and ensure that you have a server with that name.

It defaults to `connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS`. Ensure you tweak that as per your environment.